# How can I debug/fix "missing target profile", "ignored attribute", and "semantic override" errors with HLSL for Vulkan?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, vulkan, hlsl

I am trying to learn HLSL for use with Vulkan, but I can't seem to get my program to build. I am using Visual Studio 2022 and the error list reads "MSB6006 "dxc.exe" exited with code 1."

After checking the project's log file, the error expands to:

```
FXC : warning : no output provided for debug - embedding PDB in shader container.  Use -Qembed_debug to silence this warning.
vertex_frag.hlsl(3,7): warning G8A84224D: 'location' attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]
      [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
        ^
vertex_frag.hlsl(4,7): warning G8A84224D: 'location' attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]
      [[vk::location(1)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        ^
vertex_frag.hlsl(12,7): warning G8A84224D: 'location' attribute ignored [-Wignored-attributes]
      [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
        ^
FXC : warning : semantic 'COLOR0' on field overridden by function or enclosing type [-Winline-asm]
  
  dxc failed : Target profile argument is missing
```

My HLSL vertex shader code is:

```
struct VSInput {
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Position : POSITION0;
    [[vk::location(1)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
    [[vk::location(2)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct Camera {
    float4x4 view;
    float4x4 proj;
    float3 position;
};
struct UBO {
    float dt;
    float4x4 model;
    Camera cam;
};

cbuffer ubo : register(b0, space0) { UBO ubo; }

struct VSOutput {
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
    [[vk::location(1)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

VSOutput main(VSInput input, uint VertexIndex : SV_VertexID)
{
    VSOutput output = (VSOutput) 0;
    float4x4 camMatrix = mul(ubo.cam.proj, ubo.cam.view);
    output.Position = mul(camMatrix, mul(ubo.model, input.Position));
    
    output.Color = input.Color;
    output.UVcoord = input.UVcoord;
    
    return output;
}
```

and my HLSL prixel/fragment shader code is:

```
struct PSInput {
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
    [[vk::location(1)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};
struct PSOutput {
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

PSOutput main(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    PSOutput output = (PSOutput) 0;
    output.Color = input.Color;
    return output;
}
```

I read that there is an implicit Vulkan namespace in HLSL that adds the `[[vk::location(#)]]` attribute among others, but I have not included a Vulkan namespace anywhere in the project. I hope the implicit nature of the namespace is just going over my head, but that would not explain the "missing target profile" error, the "location attribute ignored" error, nor the override error.

There is a section in the [Khronos Group Vulkan-Guide Github](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Guide/blob/main/chapters/hlsl.adoc) called "Runtime compilation using the library" that gives code to compile HLSL to SPIR-V at runtime. However, for the moment I am just trying to build the project without necessarily compiling the HLSL files. Am I missing something, or do I just need to include this code to be able to build the project?

Comment: The profile error is because the compiler doesn't know if you're compiling for a vertex shader, pixel shader, geometry shader, etc. The other warnings are completely disparate and I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there some way to let the compiler know which is which? There is a section in the project properties for HLSL compiling called "shader type." The jit compiler in the guide I linked specifies the compile type based on the file extension (.vert, .frag, etc.), but is it possible to do the same for files with the .hlsl extension through the project properties or some other method?

Comment: In "project properties" -> "hlsl compiling" there is a setting called "all resources bound." Setting that to "no" fixed all the other errors except for the profile error.

Comment: All HLSL files you wish to be compiled should have the `.hlsl` extension. If using the Visual Studio property pages to compile shader files, you set the _Shader Type_ field to the right value in the dropdown menu, found within **HLSL Compiler->All Options**

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio what if my project has multiple different shader files? e.g. an `.hlsl` for a vertex shader and another for a pixel/fragment shader. Is it possible to compile both when building the project solution? Would that just be setting the _Shader Type_ field to `/vs /ps`?

Comment: Update: I just figured it out. For some reason the properties of the `.hlsl` file for my vertex shader did not populate correctly, so the _Shader Type_ field was blank for the file's **HLSL Compiler** settings. Filling it with the correct values allowed the project to build successfully. 

Thank you everyone for your guidance towards the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the commenters, I was able to find out the source of the errors. Since I was just testing the `.hlsl` files' functionality, I did not bind any resources to the shaders, so the build failed when trying to find the bound resources. To fix this, go to **Project Properties -> HLSL Compiler -> General**, locate the *All Resources Bound* field, and set it to `No`. After building the project again, the only error remaining was:

```
dxc failed : Target profile argument is missing
```

To fix this error, make sure that your `.hlsl` files' properties have been configured correctly. Right click on the `.hlsl` file and select **Properties -> HLSL Compiler -> General**. This time, locate the *Shader Type* field and set it to the appropriate shader type using the dropdown menu.

My project built successfully after completing all of these steps, and no errors were encountered.